# XY Scatter Chart with Smooth Line doesn't consider Time in DateTime X-Axis

Tags: excel, charts

Here is my sample data

[image]

and here is the graph generated by XY Scatter Chart with Smooth Line in Excel 2010.

[image]

The data type of column TIME in the table and X-Axis is changed to TIME. However, only date is considered and The time axis is ignored in the graph and is always considered as '12:00'. Is there any particular setting to enable the time to be considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spirit that it might help someone, here is the answer.. I modified a setting in X-Axis options. By Default, Major Unit is 'Auto', I think the value is 0.5 which indicates half a day, which is why I think 12:00 AM & 12:00 PM are displayed. I changed it to '0.2'. It will give intermediate values in the graph. This value can be changed as required.

[image]